# Insert..Select, same column different values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got this table with the following:

```
part_id  |  feature_name  | feature_value  |  feature_unit  |
_____________________________________________________________
   1     |     Weight     |      2         |       kg       |
   1     |     Color      |     Blue       |                |
   1     |   Description  |description here|                |
```

What i wanted to do was place these in another (new)table

```
part_id  |   description  |  color  | weight  |
_______________________________________________
   1     |description here|   Blue  |   2kg   |
```

I thought of using the Insert..Select depending on the value of the feature_value column but cant seem to build the right query for this.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting columns to rows, you can use `case based aggregation` for this.

```
INSERT into newTable(part_id, description, color, weight)
SELECT part_id
       max( case when feature_name ='Description' 
                 then feature_value end ) as description,
       max( case when feature_name ='Color' 
                 then feature_value end ) as Color,
       max( case when feature_name ='weight' 
                 then concat(feature_value,feature_unit) end ) as weight
FROM my_table
GROUP BY part_id
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with conditional aggregation:

```
select part_id,
       max(case when feature_name = 'description' then feature_value end) as description,
       max(case when feature_name = 'color' then feature_value end) as color,
       max(case when feature_name = 'weight' then concat(feature_value, feature_unit) end) as weight
from thistable
group by part_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this select

```
select t1.part_id, t1.feature_value, t2.feature_value, t3.feature_value from table t1 inner join table t2 on t1.part_id = t2.part_id and t2.feature_name = 'Color' inner join table t3 on t1.part_id =t3.part_id and t3.feature_name='Weight' where t1.feature_name = 'Description'
```